# R: Combining "vline" and "hline" statements together (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I am working with the R programming language. Recently, I learned how to "draw" horizontal and vertical lines with the ggplot library:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Simple scatter plot
sp <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()

# Add horizontal line at y = 2O

a = sp + geom_hline(yintercept=20) 

b = sp + geom_vline(xintercept = 3)
```

[image]

Now, I am trying to combine these statements together - for example:

```
c = sp + geom_hline(yintercept=20) +  geom_hline(yintercept=15) + geom_vline(xintercept = 3) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 5) + geom_vline(xintercept = 6) + geom_hline(yintercept=35)
```

[image]

**Question:** I am trying to modify the above plot so that it looks like this:

[image]

Can someone please show me how to do this? Or do you have to manually export this plot into Microsoft Paint and change it over there?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a layer using `annotate`. Each segment is a matched element of the four vectors below. ie the first segment starts at (-Inf,15) and ends at (3,15).

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
  annotate("segment", 
           x = c(-Inf, 3, -Inf, 5, -Inf, 6),
           y = c(15, 15, 20, 20, 35, 35),
           xend = c(3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6),
           yend = c(15, -Inf, 20, -Inf, 35, -Inf))
```

[image]

Or perhaps it would be easier to define a function which draws two lines from a point toward the axes (assuming here the point is positive so it should head toward -Inf). To make a function output multiple ggplot2 elements, put them in a list:

```
draw_guides<- function(x, y) {
  list(geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = x, y = y, yend = y)),
       geom_segment(aes(x = x, xend = x, y = y, yend = -Inf)))
}
```

Then you can call each one to recreate the desired figure more easily:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
  draw_guides(3,15) +
  draw_guides(5,20) +
  draw_guides(6,35)
```